# Assume that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is function such that any integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(x)dx$ is finite ...

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to know if the following statement is true.

> Assume that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is function such that any integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(x)dx$ is finite and there exists a limit $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(x)dx$ that is finite.
>
> Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)dx$ exist and is finite.

How to prove it or find some counter-example?

Comment: Is it a Riemann integral of a Lebesgue one?

Comment: Is is a Lebesgue.

Answer (score 2):

**The claim is false**.

I give a counterexample. I denote $d\mu(x)$ for Lebesgue integral and $dx$ for Riemann integral.

Take $$g(x)=\mathbf{1}_{x> 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\mathbf{1}_{x=0}$$ Note that there is no need to integrate on $(-\infty,0]$. Since this function is Riemann integrable on $[0,t]$ for all $t>0$ we have:
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,t]}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,d\mu(x) = \int^t_0 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx
\end{align} 
Hence:
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{[0,t]}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,d\mu(x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int^t_0 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}
Finite and all. However $\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,d\mu(x)$ does not even exist, since $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225439/showing-frac-sin-xx-is-not-lebesgue-integrable-on-mathbbr-ge-0) for a proof.

Comment: I understand that $\int_{[0,\infty)}\left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right|d\mu(x)=\infty$, but it means that $\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{sin(x)}{x}d\mu(x)$ does not exist?

Comment: @Lukaszmat yes, because what is the definition of lebesgue integrability? That $\int |f|\, d\mu<\infty$.  Remember?

Comment: Yes, but maybe this integral exists and is equal $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Comment: @Lukaszmat no it just does not exist. Lebesgue does not deal with not absolutely convergent integrals. Are you sure you know the definition of Lebesgue integral?

Comment: For example. Assume that we have function $f(x)=1$ on real line. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f(x)\right|d\mu(x)=\infty$ but $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)d\mu(x)$ exist and is equal $\infty$. For me exist does  not mean that it is finite.

Comment: For me does not exist means that $\int f^+=\infty$ and $\int f^-=\infty$

Comment: @Lukaszmat okay if that is the case, then with the function $g(x) $ we surely have $\int g^+\, d\mu=\infty $ and $\int g^-\, d\mu=\infty $. One can easily change the proofs given in the link I provided so that you get that the positive and the negative part both diverge to infinity.

Comment: @Lukaszmat We use MCT to link the Lebesgue integral with the Riemann integral, just use $g_n(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}g^+(x)$ and get:
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,\infty)} g^+(x)\,d\mu(x)=\int^\infty_0 g^+(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Moreover:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 g^+(x)\,dx&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int^{(2k+1)\pi}_{2k\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\\
&\geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}\int^{(2k+1)\pi}_{2k\pi} \sin(x)\,dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}\\
&=\infty
\end{align} The same can be done for $g^-$. So.... Conclude!

Comment: Ok, now I understand :)