# Why is $\sin(x)/x$ not Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$. Consider the following:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx = 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\chi_{[-n,n]}dx$$

so that each $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\chi_{[-n,n]}dx$ is Riemann integrable
and so it is Lebesgue integrable (integrating over compact space). Since
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\chi_{[-n,n]}dx \to \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx$ and
so by completeness of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, we have that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ so in particular,
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx < \infty$ in the Lebesgue integral sense.

I know I have made a mistake here somewhere but I am having trouble seeing *exactly* where. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225439/7266) is related...

Comment: I know but I arrived at the conclusion that this function IS Lebesgue integrable using (what I assume is) faulty logic. Therefore, I thought this was worth asking in a different thread (not sure if this is the right word). I already know it is a well established fact that this function is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is complete with respect to the $L^1$ norm. You would need to show that $f\chi_{[-n,n]}$ converges to $f$ in the $L^1$ norm and not just pointwisely. In fact, $\| f \chi_{[-n,n]} \|_1$ is not even bounded, so the sequence does not converge in $L^1$. It is easier to see the error if you just consider the sequence $\chi_{[-n,n]}$ on $\mathbb R$. Each function is $L^1$, but it does not converge with respect to the norm and the pointwise limit of the functions is clearly not in $L^1$.

Comment: @TrevorNorton That should be an answer.

Comment: thank you for that comment Trevor, I see where I went wrong now. I thought it was a general fact that $f\chi_{[-n,n]}\to f$. I see that I am wrong now.

Comment: @TrevorNorton You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have submitted my comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$L^1(\mathbb R)$ is complete with respect to the $L^1(\mathbb R)$ norm. You would need to show that $f\cdot\chi_{[−n,n]}$ converges to $f$ in the $L^1$ norm and not just pointwisely. In fact, $\|f\cdot\chi_{[−n,n]}\|_1$ is not even bounded, so the sequence does not converge in $L^1$. It is easier to see the error if you just consider the sequence $\chi_{[-n,n]}$. Each function is $L^1$, but it does not converge with respect to the norm and the pointwise limit of the functions is clearly not in $L^1$.

Comment: +1 for being super clear and complete

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So is this a Banach answer?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek what do you mean by Banach answer ?

Comment: @AnmolBhullar This is just a joke, because Severin said that your answer is complete. A Banach space is a complete normed space, complete in the sense of Cauchy sequences. You can safely ignore this comment.

Comment: @TheGreekGeek Indeed, pun intended ^^

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that your sequence is not a Cauchy sequence and thus you cannot use the completeness of $L^1$.