# Is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ Lebesgue-Integrable?

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to understand why $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not integrable according to Lebesgue over $\mathbb{R}$

If found this answer that helped me a lot but don't understand how the Monotone Convergence Theorem was used

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3184570/741674

Can someone help me by detailing the problematic line in this answer?

Thank you

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that you can sidestep the issue and just notice that over the intervals $[2\pi + \pi/6, 2\pi + 5\pi/6]$ this function is bounded below by $\frac{1}{2x}$, which allows a more elementary argument (even to the level of integral simple functions, if one desires!) based on the divergence of the harmonic series.

Answer (score 3):

The author is applying the MCT to the non-decreasing sequence of functions $$f_N(x)=\sum_{k=0}^N\Bbb{1}_{[{2k\pi},\, {(2k+1)\pi}]}(x)\frac{\sin(x)}x $$
where $$\Bbb 1_S(x)=\cases{1 & if $x \in S$,\\0 & otherwise.}$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir !

Comment: @jp.perk You're welcome!