# Is $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-xy}$ integrable for $x\in ]0,\infty[$ and $y \geq 0$?

Tags: definite-integrals

- Is $\left]0,\infty\right[ \to \mathbb{R},\,\,\, \operatorname{f}\left(x\right) =
  \frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}\,\,{\rm e}^{-xy}\,\,\,$ Lebesgue-integrable for $\,\,\, y \geq 0\ ?$.
- I tried $\,\,\,\left\vert\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)\right\vert \leq \left\vert\,{\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}}\,\right\vert,\,\,\,$ but I don't know whether $\,\,\,\left\vert\,{\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}}\,\right\vert\,\,\,$ is integrable.

Maybe I am taking a wrong direction..

Comment: To be clear: We're viewing $y$ as a constant, right?

Comment: $y\gt 0$ OK.  $y=0$ then $\int_0^\infty \frac{sinx}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$  Using absolute value doesn't work, integral in infinite...

Comment: yes, y is a constant. bigger or equal 0. I don't understand you - so you are saying, that for y>0 it definitely is integrable?

Comment: As a hint, $\sin(x)/x$ is _not_ Lebesgue integrable. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225439/showing-frac-sin-xx-is-not-lebesgue-integrable-on-mathbbr-ge-0) for instance

Comment: For $y > 0$, try comparing to $e^{-yx}/x$ rather than $\sin(x)/x$ to see that you're integrable.

Comment: This seems also being very difficult to integrate - but if its integrable, then I'm happy enough :)

Comment: If you know $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}x\right| \leq 1$, it may instead be easier to directly compare with $|f(x)| \leq e^{-yx}$ instead (the only true difference is for $x\approx 0$, where $e^{-yx}/x$ has problems)

Answer (score 1):

Just for curiosity. Observe that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin (\alpha x)}{x} e^{-yx}\ dx =&\ \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{i\alpha x}-e^{-i\alpha x}}{2i x}e^{-xy}\ dx\\
=&\ \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{i\alpha x}}{2i x}e^{-xy}\ dx- \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-ix}}{2i x}e^{-xy}\ dx\\
=&\ \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{i\alpha x}}{2i x}e^{-xy}\ dx+\int^0_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{2ix}e^{xy}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\alpha x}\frac{e^{-y|x|}}{ix}\ dx.
\end{align}
Notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin (\alpha x)}{x} e^{-yx}\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\alpha x}e^{-y|x|}\ dx = \frac{y}{y^2+\alpha^2}.
\end{align}
Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin (\alpha x)}{x} e^{-yx}\ dx = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\alpha}{y} \right).
\end{align}
Set $\alpha = 1$ gives us the desired result.